# Lightning Testing service failing for apex

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-testing-service, jasmine

I am trying to mock the apex method  response and trying to test attributes with the fake response.But It is failing.

**I am getting error message:
Error:Expected 0 to be 1 
Error:Expected false to be true 
In the component i am setting apex response to the attribute named ‘data’ .
and based on the response length is greater than zero i am setting mybool attribute as true.
I am testing the both scenario by creating mock apex response and checking the length of data attribute expecting to be one and mybool attribute value to be true because mock response has one value.**

```
 <aura:component controller="TreeController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force :lightningQuickAction" access="global">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>
<aura:attribute name="data" type="List" default="[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="mybool" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<div style="height: 300px">
    <lightning:datatable
            keyField="id"
            data="{! v.data }"
            columns="{! v.columns }"
            hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
</div> 
</aura:component>



({
init : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.columns', [
        {label: 'name', fieldName: 'name', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'parent', fieldName: 'parent', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'expanded', fieldName: 'expanded', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'label', fieldName: 'label', type: 'text'}
    ]);
    var action = component.get("c.getTreeData");  
    //action.setParams({ accountId : component.get("v.recordId")});
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {  
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log('state'+state);
        console.log('response'+JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {  
             var result = response.getReturnValue();
             console.log('response size'+response.getReturnValue().length);
             if(response.getReturnValue().length>0){
               component.set('v.mybool',true);  
             }
             component.set('v.data',result);
       }  
 });  
 $A.enqueueAction(action);  
}
})
```

Server-side controller

```
public class TreeController {
   @AuraEnabled  
   public static List<Account> getAccountList(Id accountId) {  
     List<Account> finalvalue = new List<Account>();  
     for(Account accA : [ Select Id, Name,(SELECT Id,Contact.Name,parentId__c, Phone FROM contacts),ParentId,ImmediateChildFlag__c,ImmediateParent__c,ImmediateParent__r.Name From Account Where ParentId =: accountId or Name LIKE'TreeAccount%']) {   
          finalvalue.add(accA);  
         }            
     System.debug('finalvalue:::' + finalvalue);  
     return finalvalue;    
   }
   @AuraEnabled  
   public static List<TreeWrapper> getTreeData() {  
     List<TreeWrapper> treeList = new List<TreeWrapper>();  
     for(Account accA : [ Select Id, Name,(SELECT 
 Id,Contact.Name,parentId__c,AccountId, Phone FROM contacts),ParentId,ImmediateChildFlag__c,ImmediateParent__c,ImmediateParent__r.Name From Account]) {   
         TreeWrapper newTree = new TreeWrapper();
         newTree.name=accA.Id;
         newTree.parent=accA.ImmediateParent__c;
         newTree.expanded=true;
         newTree.label=accA.Name;
         treeList.add(newTree);  
              for(contact cont:accA.contacts){
                  TreeWrapper newTreeCont = new TreeWrapper();
                      newTreeCont.name=cont.Id;
                      if(cont.parentId__c==null){
                         newTreeCont.parent=cont.AccountId;
                      }
                      else{
                         newTreeCont.parent=cont.parentId__c;
                      }
                      newTreeCont.expanded=true;
                      newTreeCont.label=cont.Name;
                  treeList.add(newTreeCont); 
              }
         }            
     System.debug('treeList:::' + treeList);  
     return treeList;    
   }
   public class TreeWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled
        public String name;
        @AuraEnabled
        public String parent;
        @AuraEnabled
        public Boolean expanded;
        @AuraEnabled
        public String label;
        public TreeWrapper(){
            this.name = '';
            this.parent = '';
            this.expanded = false;
            this.label = '';
          }
        }
       }
```

LTS script:

```
describe("Testing the component", function(){

    /*** JUST CHECKING JASMINE ***/

    describe("A test suite that tests the obvious", function() {
      it("spec that verifies that true is true", function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
      });
      it("spec that verifies that false is false", function() {
        expect(false).toBe(false);
      });
    });

     describe('c:mycomp', function() {
            it('check the wrapper apex method', function(done) {
            $T.createComponent("c:mycomp", null, true)
                .then(function(component){
                    var res = {
                                    getState : function(){
                                        return "SUCCESS";
                                    }, 
                                    getError : function(){
                                        return "ERRORS";
                                    }, 
                                    getReturnValue: function(){
                                        return [{"expanded":true,"label":"Greer122 Inc","name":"0014100000BHOUfAAP"}];
                                    }
                              };
                 spyOn($A, "enqueueAction").and.callFake(function(action) {
                        var cb = action.getCallback("SUCCESS")
                        cb.fn.apply(cb.s,[res]);
                    });                           
                    // Assert using components interface
                    expect(component.get("v.data").length).toBe(1);
                    expect(component.get("v.mybool")).toBe(true);
                    done();
                }).catch(function(e) {
                    done.fail(e);
                   });
        });
    });

});
```

Application

```
<aura:application>
<c:lts_jasmineRunner testFiles="{!$Resource.lts_comptest}" />
</aura:application>
```

Comment: If you'd like the swiftest and most accurate response from the community, please **[edit] your question** to include very specific details of the failure you are observing.

Comment: @DavidReed i have added some more points with the error.